# Why does my hard drive shut down while in use (e.g. recording with OBS, copying , etc)?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a Seagate 1TB Mobile HDD which I removed from an external hard drive adapter of some sorts. [This is a photo of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo6XW.jpg) It works fine and has fair read and write speeds.

I would like to use it as my computer's third hard drive on which I will record files using OBS or ShadowPlay. It's connected using a SATA cable.

The problem is that it either hangs or totally shuts down even when I just try to open it in Explorer. It doesn't make any noise or anything. Sometimes, if I'm unlucky, it just vanishes from the computer as if it was never there, and after two or more (not one) restarts, it comes right back.

What could be the problem?

Maybe a third drive is overloading my 450W PSU, or maybe an issue with my Gigabyte GA-78LMT-S2 Motherboard?

(PS My other drives, i.e. the primary one with the OS and the secondary one with my software and games, are normal HDDs.)

Comment: Does it work at all (you mentioned it hangs when you try to open it in Explorer)?  What do the SMART statistics say?

Comment: It does work from time to time and the hangs mostly occur when i try to use it for something like After effects Cache or Obs recordings , if i dont use it for a while then try to use it , then it works just fine, Also the SMART statistics shows OK for the Drive, By the way it also doesnt show up as a seagate drive , it shows up as  samsung.

Comment: So it seems that it isn't able to handle heavy usage.  I suspect that while it's in the USB carrier, the drive doesn't get enough traffic to trip it up.  I wonder if the maker tests them ahead of time and sells the highly-capable ones as full fledged HDs and the low-capable ones for USB.  Just speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the motor on the hard drive is failing.

I don't have that specific drive, but I have had 5 or 6 other Seagate drives do this exact same thing to me.

Except I unplugged the power cord, plugged it back.  The drive works for awhile, but it will repeat over and over till it fails.

Sure you can use power monitoring software or a voltage meter to verify your 12v channel,psu, is at least 11.4v, and your 5v is at least 4.75v.  However, given my past experience with there drives, I doubt this is the problem.

If your voltages are below or new said thresholds then you need a larger power supply.